# Android: Trying to change color from string

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to change the string color between these character `* *`, but something went wrong with my code. The application is finished. 
Every "nota" that contains `"*"` (i.e. `This is * good *` ) should change the color of the rest of word "good" and erase `"*"` characters

```
if(nota != null){
        if(nota.contains("* *")){

         nota = nota.replace("* *","");

         Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
         spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), nota.indexOf("* *"), nota.indexOf("* *") + "* *".length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
         txtnota.setText(spannable);

    }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I tried this code, but it is partially coloring the words (not the specific word that I want):

```
if(nota != null){
        int firstIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
        if (firstIndex >= 0) {
            nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");
            int secIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
            if (secIndex >= 0) {
                nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");

                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString("➥ "+nota);
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), firstIndex, secIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannable.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), firstIndex, secIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

                txtnota.setText(spannable);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an exception in logcat?

Comment: If you find the index of two stars, then you won't find words between two stars as you are looking for literally the string `"* *"`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see, you first remove the "*" character and after that you invoke indexOf that character, but you don't have it any more, so you get negative result. Move the replace instruction after setting span. And you shouldn't check for "* *" but for first occurence of "*" , than set span, and after that remove the two occurences of "*". Or you can keep indexes.  Here is an example of code:

```
    if(nota != null){
            int firstIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
            if (firstIndex >= 0) {
                nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");
                int secIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
                if (secIndex >= 0) {
                    nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");

                    Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
                    spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), firstIndex, secIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                    txtnota.setText(spannable);
                }
            }
    }
```

Comment: I tried your code. But nothing happened. I have a string within nota, for example "This is * good *", the stars didn't erase and good didn't change to yellow color.

Comment: Let me explain: I want to erase * star character and what comes after this or between these * * should change the color.... not the whole phrase. Just the word with * character: This is * good * as if mini-Markdown formatting. :)

Comment: Please note that you have to apply the spannable to a textView or an editText to see changes (Something like `editText.setText(spannable);`... Or where do you want to check changes? What is `txtnota` ?

Comment: ok, I put txtnota.setText(spannable);  and worked it.. but it erased the whole phrase before * astherisc... for example: This is `*good`... good changed to yellow and changed to "nota" (i don't want this) and astherisc was erased ... but "this is" was erased also....

Comment: Take a look at this question. I explained better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37516185/android-trying-to-replace-character-and-change-color-of-a-word/37516252#37516252

Comment: Delete the `String nota = "nota"; ` . I hardcoded to test it :) Let me know if it works

Comment: I deleted String nota = "*nota*"; and put also txtnota.setText(spannable); It  partially worked it. The last letter of word is not changed to yellow... for example good, the letter D is not changed.

Comment: I update my post above. Your code works partially. It continues not coloring the exact word between * *. It is coloring part of previous word too. Take a look at it :/