# Android trying to replace character and change color of a word

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I have string called nota. There is some texts. What I want is to change the color of specific words from phrase that contains * * between them. Ex.: That is * awesome*. The word `awesome` should have a yellow color and the * * characters should be erased (as if * is a mini-Markdown formatting). I tried this code, but it didn't work. I need some help.

```
 if(nota.contains("* *")){

 //nota = nota.replace("* *","");
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*.*\\*");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nota);
 // Check all occurrences
 matcher.find();


 Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
 spannable.setSpan(
 //new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), nota.indexOf("* *"), nota.indexOf("* *") + "* *".length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
 new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), matcher.start() + 1 , matcher.end() - 1,     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 txtnota.setText(spannable);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved it in this way:

```
if(nota != null){
        int firstIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
        if (firstIndex >= 0) {
            nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");
            int secIndex = nota.indexOf("*");
            if (secIndex >= 0) {
                nota = nota.replaceFirst("[*]{1}", "");

                Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
                spannable.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), firstIndex, secIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                spannable.setSpan(new android.text.style.StyleSpan(android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC), firstIndex, secIndex, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                txtnota.setText(spannable);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `.Contains("* *")` would detect the following strings:

```
* * awesome!
Hello boy! * *
Hello* * boy!
```

But not:

```
*awesome*
```

Try changing your code to:

```
if( nota.contains("*") && nota.replace("*","").contains("*") ){

 //nota = nota.replace("* *","");
 Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\*.*\\*");
 Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(nota);
 // Check all occurrences
 matcher.find()


 Spannable spannable = new SpannableString(nota);
 spannable.setSpan(
 //new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), nota.indexOf("* *"), nota.indexOf("* *") + "* *".length(),     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE
 new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), matcher.start() + 1 , matcher.end() - 1,     Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
 txtnota.setText(spannable);
 }
```

What `nota.replace("*","").contains("*")` basically does is to check if you have 2 astherics *

Comment: I tried your code. I followed your steps and put `*awesome*`, but nothing changed. The astherics is visible and no yellow color is inserted for awesome.